# How do I set default for phone type?

Tags: phone

I want to auto default phone type as home - can't locate where/how to manage that. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One sets the default location type for all contact info (phone/address/email).  They can't be set separately unless you write an extension.  You can change it at **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Dropdown Options » Location Types**.  Click "Edit" next to "Home" and check the "Default?" box.